# How to share a string using Python 3's multiprocessing.Value?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, ctypes

I am trying to share a string between two processes using Value, but it does not work.

```
from multiprocessing import Value, Process
import time
import ctypes
def say_hi(v):
    with v.get_lock():
        print(f"Saying hi with {v.value=:}")
        v.value = "borat"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v = Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, "boris")
    p1 = Process(target=say_hi, args=(v,))
    p2 = Process(target=say_hi, args=(v,))

    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

The first process is supposed to set the string to "borat" but the output is:

`Saying hi with v.value=boris`

`Saying hi with v.value=`

Comment: You're only sharing a pointer between processes; the memory being pointed to is within the private memory of each process, and is not shared.  You want to use an `Array` instead, of some character type, so that the actual text is in shared memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to use c_char_p type for this operation (then you can perform decoding):

```
    from multiprocessing import Value, Process
    import time
    import ctypes
    def say_hi(v):
        with v.get_lock():
            print(f"Saying hi with v.value={v.value.decode()}.")
            v.value = b'borat'
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        v = Value(ctypes.c_char_p, b"boris")
        p1 = Process(target=say_hi, args=(v,))
        p2 = Process(target=say_hi, args=(v,))
    
        p1.start()
        p1.join()
    
        p2.start()
        p2.join()
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the original code.  A *pointer* is shared but the value is not valid in another process's memory space.

Comment: If this has the same problem, how come it prints out the right output?

Comment: In python 3.10, it does not work! AttributeError: 'Synchronized' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 0):

Use an `Array` to pass the shared memory itself, and not just the pointer value.  A pointer is only valid in the process that created it.

```py
from multiprocessing import Array, Process

def say_hi(v):
    with v.get_lock():
        print(f'Saying hi with {v.get_obj().value=:}')
        v.get_obj().value = 'borat'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = Array('u', 'boris')
    p1 = Process(target=say_hi, args=(v,))
    p2 = Process(target=say_hi, args=(v,))

    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

Output:

```
Saying hi with v.get_obj().value=boris
Saying hi with v.get_obj().value=borat
```